# Plural form of "olio"

Tags: orthography, nouns, plural, grammatical-number

Wikipedia lists [some rules](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plurale_delle_parole_in_-io) and suggests that the plural form of *olio* is *olii*.
I used to think that *oli* sounds (and writes) better, and [Dizionario d'ortografia e di pronunzia](http://www.dizionario.rai.it/poplemma.aspx?lid=32480&r=977) confirms that.
[Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/olio/), however, suggests yet another plural form, with circumflex: *olî*.

Any rule of thumb I could use?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

We can derive a general rule (with loads of exceptions, like everything in this language) from this case. When the expected plural form of a word contains a non-stressed double *i*, like "olio" -> "olii", "principio" -> "principii", there's a tendency to drop the second *i*: "oli", "principi" (Ngrams for "[olii](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=olii&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1;,olii;,c0)" vs "[oli](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=oli&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1;,oli;,c0)" confirm this graphically). However, some speakers do retain a memory of the double *i* in their pronunciation of such words, the *i* is slightly longer.

To tell a "single-*i*-that-used-to-be-double" from an ordinary single *i* the circumflex accent can be used and this is standard Italian grammar. This makes sense particularly when one needs to disambiguate, for example "principî" (plural of "principio", principle) as opposed to "principi" (plural of "principe", prince); this is the solution used in the Italian Constitution that includes a chapter called *Principî fondamentali*. Another solution in this case is the tonic accent: "principî" can be unambiguously written as "princìpi" because the other word is read as "prìncipi".

Conclusion: the three forms ("olii", "oli" and "olî") are equally acceptable, but as you can imagine the circumflex accent is unusual and most people wouldn't even be able to type it on their keyboard. AFAIK, this is the only case in which a circumflex accent can be used in Italian words not borrowed from foreign languages or dialects, I guess most Italians wouldn't even realise that in their language this accent exists.

Notice that the situation is entirely different with *stressed* plurals in *-ii* (e.g. "sgocciolìo" -> "sgocciolii"). In this case the double *i* is pronounced clearly by all speakers (the first *i* is stressed) and is compulsory. The opposite applies to nouns ending in *-cio*, *-glio*, *-scio* etc. where the *i* is not really used as a vowel: the plural form requires one *i*.

Comment: You forget to mention that the letter *j* was often used as a second *i*: http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/verit-prego-plurale-termini

Comment: @Sklivvz Such usage of _j_ is definitely obsolete though.

Comment: Not more than the circumflex accent, in my opinion.

Comment: @Sklivvz The circumflex accent is standard 2014 Italian, even though it's seldom used. The _j_ is just obsolete. I gave the example of the Constitution, it contains the circumflex but it does not contain the _j_. The Crusca article you quoted states precisely this: the circumflex accent is OK, the _j_ is not.

Comment: A ton of Italian books still use it, e.g. Manzoni (I think), so it should be mentioned as an example of spelling that is possible but should not be used. Note that I used the past form in my first comment: "...*was* often used...".

Comment: @Sklivvz 21st-century Italian does not use 18th-century Manzoni's Italian as a reference for spelling rules. This language has changed in the last centuries much faster than English. However, I just checked the full text of "I promessi sposi" and Manzoni does not use the _j_. This letter is only used for plurals when Manzoni quotes *16th*-century "grida". Bottom line: the _j_ sounded ancient and obsolete already at Manzoni's ears! :-)

Answer (score 8):

Using *î* instead of *ii* is something that was once done, but nowadays that is not done anymore, at least on everyday usage. Between *olii* and *oli*, I would expect the latter to be used more often than the former, at least because it requires you to  write less letters, and generally there is no confusion about what *oli* means. (It would not be taken as plural of *olo*, since that is not an Italian word.)

*Lo Zingarelli* reports just two plural word for *olio*: *oli* and *olii*.

Comment: There is a long list of words for which the plurals in *-i* and in *-ii* (or *-î*) belong to different words, from *assassini(i)* to *vari(i)*, including *geni*, *osservatori*, *omicidi*, *secchii*...

Comment: @DaG: *secchii* e *varii*??? Seriously? I would definitely take those as spelling errors. I have seen *assassini* e *assassinii* used to distinguish between the plurals of *assassino* and *assassinio*, but still it is quite rare.

Comment: I have never seen _secchii_ being used as plural of _secchio_, since _secchi_ is an adjective. There is no possibility of confusion between _rami secchi_ and _i secchi riempiti di acqua e detersivo_.

Comment: “There is no possibility of confusion” is not in itself alone always a reason to justify orthographic norms. For instance, *da* (from) and *dà* (he gives) can hardly be confused, but they are written differently. And *La vecchia porta la sbarra* teaches that ambiguity is always behind the corner.

Comment: @DaG Accents are obligatory when they fall on the last vowel; it's not a matter of confusion. I didn't say that "no possibility of confusion" is the only criterion, but surely it is an important factor, since normally people don't use more than it is needed, including accents or additional letters.

Comment: @DaG: no possibility of confusion may not be a criterion, but then again possibility of confusion does not justify putting a double `i` either...

Answer (score 4):

I'd add that if an adjective follows, like "oli vegetali", the form with a single "i" is commoner (curiosly, a quick googling shows that "olii vegetali" is mainly used by people which write about organic products and the like)

Comment: Exactly. Some articles about organic food with "olii vegetali" were actually the reason, why I've asked about it in the first place.

Comment: Well, I don't know about everyone else, but personally, whenever I hear this, I tend to hear both of the "ii" in "oli". Most of the time I hear "olii". There may be variations in the way peole pronounce this word, and these may or may not be regional variations.

Answer (score 0):

One should always check and double-check what Wikipedia says, but in this particular case, I'd agree with its distinction between compulsory *-ii* in the case of a stressed *i* in *-io*, and multiple possibilities (*-i*, *-ii*, and *-î*) for an unstressed one.

Comment: Where `-î` is rarely found nowadays (thank goodness).

Comment: Why “thank goodness”?

Comment: Because it's horrible and has nothing to do with Italian orthography. It's an accent borrowed at some point in time from French. You missed another used orthography, though: `olj`, which Pirandello would probably have used.

Comment: @egreg To me, *olj* somehow looks even worse that *olî*...

Comment: @I.M. Of course I agree! But it used to be a possible orthography.

Comment: Pirandello and Verga's usage of j was a great idea, too bad we don't use it anymore.

Comment: I never heard “horrible” and “circumflex accent” in the same argument. Every day teaches us something! :-)

Comment: @MatteoItalia Is it possible that Pirandello and Verga's usage of j was related to some Sicilian language peculiarity?

Comment: @egreg Are you sure the circumflex accent comes from French? However, it's pretty standard even if very formal, and Italian has imported stuff from everyhwere...

And no, I don't believe that the usage of _j_ has much to do with Sicily. The _j_ was a standard way to indicate the semi-consonantic _i_ like in _buio_ / _bujo_ and an unstressed _ii_ can be seen as _ji_ (* _buji_ > _buj_).

Comment: @mauro It's possible that the accent itself snuck its way in from French, but from what I can tell it's not being used in at all the same way in this double-i case. In French the circumflex is used to denote an S that was deleted and is no longer pronounced: *forêt* (forest), *hôpital* (hospital). The [Italian version doesn't seem related](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumflex#Abbreviation.2C_contraction.2C_and_disambiguation).

Comment: Circumflex accent in itself (apart from its different uses in different languages) predates by far French and Italian: it was used, in different shapes and functions, in Ancient Greek and Latin. See for instance the article “Accento grafico” in Treccani's *Enciclopedia dell'italiano* (http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/accento-grafico_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)/), and the works cited there.

Comment: I haven't seen any French words with the circumflexed "î" in the final position (but there may be cases I'm not familiar, perhaps someone can point them out). On the other hand, the concept of using a circumflex to let the reader know that the following letter has been left out is common to French, but there may be a common root to this usage.

Comment: As to whether "the spelling ij" was derived from some language which at one time was spoken in Sicily, I would bet you that's correct. To prove my point, Anyone who's been to Malta on vacation and seen the signs on the streets will notice so many spelling of "ij", which the Maltese sound out as an "i" followed by some sort of "emphatic rolled double-i" which is represented by the "j". Due to the historical influence of Sicily in Malta, this is the only place this spelling could have come from. Regards.

Comment: E perché questo voto negativo adesso?

Answer (score -1):

In Italy we never use olî. Also olii is not so common, even if it's better than oli.

Comment: that's not really an answer.

Comment: the question was «Any rule of thumb I could use?» The answer is «Don't use olî, and prefer oli to olii». For me it is a bona fide answer.

Comment: @mau Here at SE network, I'd call an answer only those explanations, which (a) provide some reliable references; (b) explain *why* one form is preferred to another. "We never" and "not so common but better" don't make a good answer.

Comment: I agree that *oli* is better than *olii*, but only stating this doesn't make this an answer.

Comment: Let me be a little fastidious here... Well, to me that's an answer: "in Italy we do this". The person that asked the question asked for a *rule of thumb*. Nothing is better as a rule of thumb that an answer given by an Italian that in school had almost all A in all his italian language and literature courses and uses the language everyday. :-)

Comment: @Napolux The thing is: everybody here, including myself, speaks Italian every day, so we all are perfectly aware of what is "common", "normal" and "usual". Both the rules of the SE network and normal logic require that every answer here is supported with some references and explanations. Besides, you statement "we never" was plainly wrong: it's old orthography, which is no longer common but still can be seen in some books and even dictionaries.

Comment: So this is an italian language Q&A website for italians made in english? Really funny. I'm off, then. I thought this was a Q&A website for foreign students that wanted to learn italian.

Comment: @Napolux It is both a site for italians and for learners, and we use both languages: http://meta.italian.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-allow-questions-answers-to-be-in-italian

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to include all the essential parts of the answer here, and provide links for reference. The "long *i*" spelling is at the very least *recognized* as an archaic spelling by Italian readers. It could be used by an author writing a fiction book set in the XIX century, for example. Furthermore, the statement about the commonality of usage should be researched or expanded and "better then *oli*" should definitely be referenced and qualified appropriately.