# Quale verbo è "odino"?

Tags: verbs

Nel libro *Le città invisibili* d'Italo Calvino ho letto:

> «Tre ipotesi si dànno sugli abitanti di Bauci: che *odino* la Terra; che la rispettino al punto d'evitare ogni contatto; che la amino com'era prima di loro e con cannocchiali e telescopi puntati in giù non si stanchino di passarla in rassegna, foglia a foglia, sasso a sasso, formica per formica, contemplando affascinati la propria assenza.»

Ho pensato che "odino" fosse la terza persona plurale del presente congiuntivo del verbo odiare, ma cercando la coniugazione in questi link

- http://www.wordreference.com/conj/ItVerbs.aspx?v=odiare
- http://www.italian-verbs.com/italian-verbs/conjugation.php?verbo=odiare

ho trovato che questa forma del verbo odiare è "odiino". Per questa ragione vi chiedo: quale verbo e quale forma del verbo è "odino"?

Comment: Quei siti sbagliano. `;-)` La forma con la doppia “i” è in disuso dalla fine dell'Ottocento.

Comment: @egreg: Se le uniche risorse in rete che non sbagliano le coniugazioni dei verbi italiani sono a pagamento... Beh, penso che questo sia un problema!

Comment: Che ci possiamo fare? Suppongo il problema sia nel fatto che *odiare* non è marcato come irregolare e quindi il programma semplicemente aggiunge le desinenze alla radice. La mia posizione personale sulla *doppia i* è che non si deve usare mai, eccetto, ovviamente, quando una delle due è la vocale tonica (*zii*, *inviino*).

Comment: @egreg: Ma, la pronuncia della forma in disuso "odiino" non sarebbe precisamente con la prima "i" tonica? La traduzione al catalano di questo vocabolo è "odiïn", con la *doppia i*, e si pronuncia con la prima "i" tonica.

Comment: No; la *i* nella radice di *odiare* non è mai tonica come invece accade in *deviare* o *inviare*.

Comment: Qui la coniugazione è riportata in modo corretto http://grammatica-italiana.dossier.net/verbi-coniugati/1820.htm

Comment: Grazie, @martina!

Comment: Secondo il libro di Roberto Tartaglione, ***Verbissimo: tutti i verbi italiani*** (Alma Edizioni, 1999) (ho dovuto aspettare finora per poter prenderlo in prestito dalla biblioteca), ci sono due modelli di coniugazione per i verbi in ***-iare***: (1) Modello **cambiare**: in questi verbi, davanti alla "i" della desinenza, la "i" della radice cade. (2) Modello **sciare**: davanti a una "i" della desinenza, la "i" della radice cade soltanto nella I e II persona plurale (noi sciamo, voi sciate) e resta nelle persone singolare e la III persona plurale (io scii, tu scii, ..., loro sciino).

Comment: Grazie al link di @martina, ho visto che **odiare** segue il modello **cambiare**.

Comment: @archiviumwebmaster: Your proposed edit to the question should be a comment. Since you don't have enough reputation to comment on this post, you can post it as an answer and then a moderator will convert it to a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

“Odino” è senz'altro la terza persona plurale del congiuntivo presente di “odiare”, e i dizionari (almeno lo Zingarelli in rete, che dà la flessione completa) la riportano in questa forma. Nell'oscillazione tra “-ii-” e “-i-” succede qui qualcosa di molto simile alla vexata quaestio [olii vs. olî vs. oli](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/1321/plural-form-of-olio), soprattutto per le forme “odi/odii” dell'indicativo e del congiuntivo.

Comment: Dove si trova lo Zingarelli in rete?

Comment: @Charo: Nel [sito della Zanichelli](http://www.zanichelli.it/ricerca/prodotti/lo-zingarelli-vocabolario-della-lingua-italiana-zingarelli-001), a pagamento.

Answer (score 2):

Dal contesto e dal resto della frase è chiaro che il verbo è, come avevi pensato, "odiare".

Leggendo [questo thread](http://www.achyra.org/cruscate/viewtopic.php?t=1686) di un forum dove si discutono questioni linguistiche, sembra addirittura che la versione con la doppia "i" sia riservata solo ai casi di ambiguità, ad es. "odi" (udire) vs. "odii" (odiare). Mi sembra sensato.

Comment: In effetti ho qualche dubbio sui coniugatori in rete. Secondo quello di WordReference “odiare” si coniugherebbe come “inviare”, il che non può essere vero, visto che l'accento è diverso fin dalla prima persona del presente indicativo.

Answer (score 1):

È il verbo “odiare”. Non è una buona idea cercare riferimenti di termini letterari su vocabolari online, perché spesso non registrano le forme auliche e gli arcaismi. Anche le grafie alternative (forme con accenti circonflessi) non sono presenti, come nel termine omografo “principi”.