# Quali sono le preposizioni giuste in questa frase?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, prepositions

Scrivendo un commento a [questo post](https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/5136/707) mi sono accorta di aver dubbi sulle preposizioni da usare nella mia frase. Quale sarebbe la forma corretta: una tra le seguenti o qualcos'altro?

> - Ho dovuto aspettare finora per poter prenderlo *in* prestito *dalla* biblioteca.
> - Ho dovuto aspettare finora per poter prenderlo *in* prestito *nella* biblioteca.
> - Ho dovuto aspettare finora per poter prenderlo *a* prestito *dalla* biblioteca.
> - Ho dovuto aspettare finora per poter prenderlo *a* prestito *nella* biblioteca.

Comment: "Prenderlo a prestito nella biblioteca" non è sbagliato, semplicemente indica che quando l'hai preso a prestito ti trovavi dentro la (nella) biblioteca. A meno che tu voglia esplicitamente rimarcare questo fatto, non si userebbe.

Comment: Al margine delle ottime risposte degli altri, esprimo una valutazione di gusto e di *opportunità*, per la quale sarò forse crocifisso ma non importa. Sei straniera, e ti sconsiglio di usare "prendere a prestito", anche quando si parla di denaro. Lo trovo affettato, di sapore vagamente burocratico e la sua rottamazione a favore del più frequentato "in" non rappresenterebbe una grossa perdita per la ricchezza del tuo italiano. La forma ragionevole tra quelle che hai elencato è la prima, evita con cura tutte le altre, e "poterlo prendere" è meglio.

Comment: @gd1: Dunque, se ho capito bene, "prendere in prestito" è l'espressione più usata.  Invece, "prendere a prestito" si usa soprattutto quando si parla di denaro, ma suona più "burocratico" e anche in questo caso è più comune dire "prendere in prestito". La frase migliore sarebbe "Ho dovuto aspettare finora per poterlo prendere *in* prestito *dalla* biblioteca".

Comment: @Charo: secondo me sì. Al di là di cosa *risulti* si possa usare o meno, la prima tra le opzioni da te proposte è l'unica a comunicare un vero senso di normalità, specie con "poterlo prendere" al posto di "poter prenderlo"... Nel tuo imparare l'italiano dovrai fare un po' di economia e francamente credo che l'espressione "prendere a prestito", con anche il problema di ricordarsi quando si può usare al posto di "...in...", sia *sacrificabile*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

L'espressione più comune è "Ho dovuto aspettare finora per poter prenderlo in prestito dalla biblioteca". Se utilizzi "prendere in prestito" stai tranquilla che non sbagli... "Prendere a prestito" non mi piace ed è una frase poco usata... si utilizza solo nel linguaggio burocratico delle banche.
 "Dalla" è corretto, mentre "nella" in questo caso stona perché l'enfasi della frase è sulla parola "prestito" che sottintende la precisazione "da chi". Al contrario se uno ti chiedesse:  "Dove hai comprato questo libro?" allora potresti eventualmente utilizzare "nella" per rispondere alla sua domanda.

Answer (score 2):

Sebbene entrambe le preposizioni *a e in* siano corrette, il loro uso dipende dal  contesto:

A prestito:

> - *Prendere a prestito* si usa generalmente con riferimento ai soldi
>
>   - Prendere a prestito una somma, degli euro etc.

In prestito:

> - *Prendere in prestito* si usa generalmente in tutti gli altri casi (soldi inclusi).
>
>   - Prendere in prestito un libro o dei  soldi.

- Vedi [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=prendere%20a%20prestito%2C%20prendere%20in%20prestito&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cprendere%20a%20prestito%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cprendere%20in%20prestito%3B%2Cc0): prendere a prestito vs prendere in prestito.

La preposizione che segue è generalmente *da/dalla*. *Nella* si riferisce  a *dentro il luogo dove ho preso in prestito* qualcosa.

Answer (score 0):

Si può adoperare sia la preposizione `in` sia la `a` quando si adopera la frase:

prendere `XX` prestito (dove al posto di XX puoi usare in o a).

Invece non si usa `nella` biblioteca ma solo `dalla`.

A mio avviso, `dalla biblioteca` indica un `complemento di origine` quindi bisogna adoperare la preposizione articolata `dalla` e non `nella`.

Il risultato finale (le frasi corrette) è:

- Ho dovuto aspettare finora per poter prenderlo in prestito dalla biblioteca.
- Ho dovuto aspettare finora per poter prenderlo a prestito dalla biblioteca.